# Парсинг сайта php

Tags: html, css

Захотел автоматизировать выкладывание контента на своем канале в телеграмме, сел писать бота на пхп.
на глаз попался хороший [сайтик](https://ru.uptodown.com/android/action-adventure) парсить решил через регекспы и file_get_contents($url);

Посмотрев на структуру сайта понял, чтобы вычленить нужную мне игрушку нужно регекспом достать что то типа `<div class="item">***</div>`
вот тут то и начались проблемы, как я подозреваю у сайта стоит какая то умная защита потому что даже если нажать f12 и CTRL+F и вставить искомую строку, оно ее не находит (0/0) (не говоря уже про пхп код)

[image: yt yfikj]

Опытным путем понял, если в поиске есть знаки `="<>/` то выдает 0/0 результатов. Если чистый текст то результаты сразу находит.

[image: нашло]

Вопрос: что это за умная система блокировки и как ее можно обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для нормального парсинга юзай композеровские либы `rmccue/requests` для запросов и `imangazaliev/didom` для разбора HTML DOM. Это первое. Второе - многие сайты подгружают данные через AJAX после загрузки основной страницы, поэтому не забывай поглядывать на вкладку Network в Инструментах разработчика в браузере, зачастую проще эмулировать AJAX-запрос от сайта. Смотри какие параметры уходят, каким методом, что приходит и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, очень помогла подсказка посмотреть во вкладке сетей) теперь я смог все вытащить)

Comment: @ВладикБогун ништяк :) действуй